# I want to sync real time location data from android after every 5 seconds on server through socket in android app

Tags: android, node.js, web-services, sockets, tcpclient

I m developing taxi app like uber, I have developed android app to get location update every 5 seconds, currently I am using retrofit to sync location data to server. But we are expecting that thousands of drivers will be sending location data every five seconds and HTTP request where connection open than send data and close will cause problems. I am trying to use TCP/IP or sockets to send data, I want socket remain open and location data keep updating and when socket get closed it connect automatically. I have not found any help from any forum regarding this issue. Need help how can I achieve this and is this approach is better or not.

Answer (score 0):

Rather Than socket updation you can go for the firebase also.
When you get the location you can push the changes to the Firebase in the following way

```
private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
```

When posting to the database you have to uniquely identify a row, just like in normal database (i.e ID, UUID), so you'll have to generate one and store into you `SharedPreferences` for example.

```
public void postToDatabase(UserLocation location) {
    DatabaseReference usersRef = myRef.child(someUUID);
    usersRef.setValue(location);
}
```

To listen for changes you have to implement a `ValueEventListener`. An example, but will have to adapt to it your needs

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                UserLocation location = new UserLocation();
                location.setLongitude((String) snapshot.child("longitude").getValue());
                location.setLatitude((String) snapshot.child("latitute").getValue());
               //Dispatch your changes in application, i.e with and EventBus
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you Chirag. Firebase is also an option, But our server end developed on Node.js and Using Mongodb. So in this project I can not use Firebase, I will need persistent socket connection solution to sync data.